# Laravel show method in resource controller returning null values

Tags: api, controller, routes, resources, laravel-6

This is my show function from **ResourceController**

```
public function show(FieldType $fieldType)
{
    return new FieldTypeResource($fieldType);
}
```

This is my **FieldTypeResource**

```
public function toArray($request)
{
    return [
        'id' => $this->id,
        'name' => $this->name,
        'fields' => FieldResource::collection($this->fields()->paginate('5')),
        'created_at' => optional($this->created_at)->diffForHumans(),
    ];
}
```

This is returning data from **Postman**

```
"data": {
    "id": null,
    "name": null,
    "fields": [],
    "created_at": null
}
```

Route here

```
Route::apiResource('/fieldtypes', 'FieldTypeController');
```

Url:

```
http://someurl.local/api/fieldtypes/1
```

Tried `php artisan route:config`, `php artisan route:clear`, `Route::get('/fieldtypes/{fieldtype}', 'FieldTypeController@show');`

The request from the url have no value when printing it

Comment: You have a typo in the parameter name: `fieldtype` in the route and `$fieldType` in the controller. Both should have the same case.

Comment: it was solved bro, thanks you